# Search DataBase using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to show the found word highlighted in red when a user searches for a name in the database, here is the code:

```
echo "<table class='nameList'>";
echo "<tr><h3>You have searched for <span class='red'>$query</span> ...Please find the details.</h3></tr>";
echo "<tr> <th >UN Number</th> <th>Full Name</th></tr>";    
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT UN,NAME FROM mytable WHERE (`NAME` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());
      if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){

          while($results = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

              echo "<tr><td>".$results['UN']."</td> <td>".$results['NAME']."</td></tr>";
         }

      }else{
          echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>Sorry..No results for <span class='red'>$query</span>, try again!</td><tr>";
            echo "</table>";
```

Comment: And what is the question? Your code doesn't seem to be trying to show anything in red colour.

Comment: *sidenote* Your code is vulnerable to [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29).

Comment: @user3568485 did you get your answer sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to process the `Result` before using `echo`

When the result comes from the database you will need to find your query in the result and replace it with a span that has a style of red or what you want. In the example I used `background-color=yellow;` you can change it to `color=red;`

```
    // Create a function that highlight a list of words in a string.
  function highlightWords($string, $words)
 {
    // foreach keyword as a word
    foreach ( $words as $word )
    {
        // find the word and replace it with background color = yellow , change it to red if you want.
        $string = str_ireplace($word, '<span style="background-color:yellow">'.$word.'</span>', $string);
    }

    // return the string
    return $string;
 }


// specify the words you are looking for
$words = array("Zebra");

// your string 
$string = "My Name Is Zebra will Zebra do this?";

// highlight it 
$string = highlightWords($string, $words);

// echo it
echo $string;
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
while($results = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr><td>".$results['UN']."</td> <td>".$results['NAME']."</td></tr>";
}
```

Use style in `<td>`

Example:

```
echo "<tr><td style='color:red'>".$results['UN']."</td> <td style='color:red'>".$results['NAME']."</td></tr>";
```

Comment: The question is how to highlight one word in the result. which is the query. Like when search for a word in a page. you will get the document with your request word highlighted!

Comment: can u explain more...??

Comment: When you search for the word "Zebra" in a document by using `LIKE` you will get the results that has this word right? the question is how to highlight the word "Zebra" in all results found in the database. So you can see the result in the word you searched for in RED

Comment: I think its clear... in my amswer above... how to red it ...using style color red in <td>.. ok

Comment: Your answer is not highlighting the word .. is highlighting the STRING .. ok

Comment: u mean to say... u want a word like "aaabZEBRAkkkk" in which only Zebra shouls be red in color..... am i right now..
??